# What is the difference between procedure and #'procedure in Lisp/Clojure?

Tags: lisp, clojure

What is the difference between the evaluation of double and #'double in Clojure/Lisp?

```
1:2 user=> double
#<core$double__4077 clojure.core$double__4077@1acd47>
1:3 user=> #'double
#'clojure.core/double
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Clojure, `#'foo` is a shorthand for `(var foo)`, which returns the *variable object* `foo` refers to, as opposed to its value.  Look it up in the reference:

- [Macro Characters](http://clojure.org/reader#toc2)
- [var](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc6).

I am not sure if you also want to know the meaning in Lisp:  In Common Lisp, `#'foo` is a shorthand for `(function foo)`, which is used to access the *function value* bound to the name `foo` when not in operator position.

- [Sharpsign Single-Quote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhb.htm)
- [function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm).

Comment: slightly wrong. (function foo) looks up the functional value, true, but not necessarily from the symbol. A lexical function has no symbols involved, so it looks about the functional value bound to the name (!) foo from the lexical environment.

Comment: Right, fixed.  I really should fix my tendency to say "symbol" when I mean "name".